# Re-Add deleted files

Tags: git

I have 3 branches: `master`, `featureX` and `revertFeatureX`.

1. Create `featureX` from master and make changes.
2. Merge `featureX` into master.
3. Create `revertFeatureX` from master.
4. Delete new files and changes of `featureX` manually.
5. Merge `revertFeatureX` into master.
6. `featureX` got some new changes.

Now my problem is: When I now try to merge `featureX` again, only the changes from step 6 getting merged. But not the changes from `featureX`.

How can I bring back the changes from step 1?

Comment: Seems like you're in a bit of trouble there! Have you tried using `git cherry-pick` from the featureX commits?

Comment: `git merge` applies the changes operated on the branch since the most recent common commit. Since you merged `featureX` once, the changes operated on `featureX` before the merge are not considered; they are already present in the `master` branch (even if some of them were canceled or overwritten in the mean time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [Stuart Buckingham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4047084/stuart-buckingham) for the hint.
I solved the problem this way:

1. New branch `featureX_readd` from master
2. Cherry-pick the last commit (of step 1 in my question)
3. Merge branch `featureX` into `featureX_readd`
4. Merge `featureX_readd` into `master` -> done.

Comment: +1 because this is a much better solution than copying the file in and adding it from scratch. This way you still have your commit history. Congratulations on getting it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only one file that is missing (as your title suggests), rather than individual commits, you can checkout the old file by finding the relevant commit in your `git log` then doing `git checkout <COMMIT ID> <MISSING FILE>`

Comment: Not only one file ... I got a hint, to copy all the files, make a new branch and paste it into the new branch. Is that easier?

Comment: It maybe easier, but you will loose all of your versioning history, which sort of defeats the purpose of using git in the  first place